# Can Inferi be made out of any dead body?

Tags: harry-potter

In book six, *Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince*, the Horcrux is surrounded by a lake filled with Inferi. Did Voldemort have to use people he killed, or did Voldemort simply just go to a graveyard to procure his army of Inferni? As an example, we read in book seven that Dumbledore says that for Grindelweld the Resurrection Stone meant an army of Inferni. Does that mean he was going to have to kill a lot of people to create an army, or could he just go grave robbing?

Comment: Good start. However Connorjohnson, you have two questions here: One- **from where did Voldemort get the dead for his army of inferi**, and two: **why didn't Grindelwald use inferi as an army?**. I would suggest you to make them as two separate questions.

Comment: I was using grindelwald as an example, sorry should have clarified that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Inferi at the lake were homeless Muggles murdered by You-Know-Who

As described [here](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/inferi):

> The Inferi whom Harry and Dumbledore encounter in the depths of the lake in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* were, when alive, mostly vagrant, **homeless Muggles whom Voldemort had murdered for the purpose during his first rise to power**, although **some were the earthly remains of wizards or witches who ‘disappeared’ without explanation**.

The second part of the sentence above: *some were the earthly remains of wizards or witches who ‘disappeared’ without explanation* indicates a much darker side. You-Know-Who actually dug up the remains of dead wizards (or witches) as well to create Inferi.

Seeing what You-Know-Who used for his Inferi army to guard the Horcrux, it is clear that any body can be turned into Inferi (Muggle, wizard, recently deceased or long dead people as well).

---

### Grindelwald actually had plans of using the Inferi as an army

As mentioned in Book 7, *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Dumbledore tells Harry that Gellert Gridelwald and himself long ago tried to collect the three Hallows. For them,

The Elder Wand meant limitless invincible power.

The Resurrection Stone was the one they both wanted because for Dumbledore, it meant he could finally see his sister and apologize for what happened. And for Grindewald, the stone meant that he could raise an army of Inferi.

However they never really thought of the Invisibility Cloak and they only considered getting it so that they could **complete** the Hallows.

Comment: I will add the exact quotes from Book 7 when i get time.

Comment: I don't think "disappeared without explanation" means that he dug them up... it means they were wizards who got in his way, he killed them and turned them into inferni, and nobody ever found out what happened to those wizards.

Comment: @Theik i was referring to this: *some were the earthly remains of wizards or witches*. The *disappeared without explanation* could mean that Voldemort had them killed.

Comment: Earthly remains is a term for the bodies left behind when somebody dies, it doesn't mean "dug up from the earth", so that doesn't actually mean that you can use a dug-up body to create an inferni. It might be possible, but that sentence is not proof, sadly.